# How to re-size a table in PowerPoint using C# interop library?

Tags: c#, interop, powerpoint, tabular

I'm dynamically creating a PowerPoint using C# and I need to create a table with variable rows and columns (depends on the data which I'm processing.) The following code creates the table.

```
PowerPoint.Application pptObj = new PowerPoint.Application();
PowerPoint.Presentations presObj = pptObj.Presentation;
PowerPoint.Presentation pObj = presObj.Add(MsoTriState.msoTrue);
PowerPoint.Slides objSlides;
PowerPoint.Slide objSlide;
PowerPoint.Shapes shapes;

float pHeight = pObj.PageSetup.SlideHeight;
float pWidth = pObj.PageSetup.SlideWidth;

objSlide = objSlides.Add(1,PowerPoint.PpSlideLayout.ppLayoutTitleOnly);
shapes = objSlide.shapes;
shapes.AddTable(16,7,20,100,pWidth - 40,pHeight - 150);
```

I might have left other code details. The problem is the table not enclosed inside the slide. It goes out of it. 
I'm not able to rescale the table. Is there any other I can resize the table and fit it inside the slide irrespective of the number of rows and columns?

Answer (score 0):

Tables grow to accommodate the amount of text they hold; individual rows cannot be made to shrink to a height below what's needed to hold their text at the current font size + leading + margins and such.

So the answer to your problem is likely to be something like:

Create your table
Add all of the rows, columns and text you want to add to the table with the text in whatever maximum size you'd like.

THEN in a loop:

Reduce the text size and/or spacing and then the height of each row until the overall size of the table meets your needs.

Comment: Thank you. Looks like I have no other option other than what you said.